# Не работает пример клиент-сервер (работает только localhost)

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, qt

Нужна помощь.
Разбираюсь с сетью на Qt использую QTcpServer QTcpSocket.
За основу взял http://qt-doc.ru/model-klient-server.html этот пример также он разобран во многих местах. Компилируется и работает но только если запускать все на одном компьютере. При изменении на `MyClient     client("kor4", 2324);` или MyClient     client("192.168.1.12", 2324); не работает.

Думаю что дело не столько в коде а в сети. Запускаю Сервер на win7 (открыл порт 2324)
ip задал так 192.168.1.14 маска 255.255.255.0 шлюз 192.168.1.1 (не знаю зачем но включил telnet)
Клиент на xp ip задал так 192.168.1.12 маска 255.255.255.0 шлюз 192.168.1.1

Соединены D-Link2540u режим роут.
Фаерволы отключал
Пинг идет.

Исходники могу залить.
Укажите направление куда капать.(уже много чего перелопатил)
зы Не очень "шарю в сети".
ps есть на компе с 7кой убунту (только начал переходить на linux полный нуб)
Заранее всем спасибо.

ВОТ ИСХОДНИКИ ПРИМЕРА http://zalil.ru/33427542 Если кто-то обладает 2 компами и свободным временем скомпилируйте и проверте.
В исходнике у клиента в конструкторе поменяйте "localhost" на strHost (пример правил и забыл вернуть)

Не знаю что из этого помогло но 1 поменял себе ip 2 перекомпилировал 3 перегрузил 4 убил все что мог антивирус и т.п.4 создал правило которое обслуживает порт и убрал галочку с NAT (хотя это все я проделывал уже не раз)

Вопрос можно удалить всем спасибо.

Comment: А почему, если сервер 192.168.1.14 то в коде у вас 

    MyClient client("192.168.1.12", 2324);

Comment: это я тут ошибся

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понял: сервер под Win7, а клиент под WinXP? Ping на сервер Win7 дает отклик, а программа-сервер не дает эхо? Судя по-всему проблема в настройках безопасности сети в Win7, Вам необходимо разрешить клиенту получать данные (или серверу отдавать данные соответствующему клиенту). А Ping, по-ходу, должен проходить в данной конфигурации сети.

Comment: Есть готовый пример я только учусь работать с сетью и сокетами. Так этот пример не работает если его запустить как положено на разных "машинах",
если запустить на одном компе то работает.

Comment: Тогда проверьте Вашу клиент-серверную программу на одинаковых платформах (WinXP). Если все нормально - проблема в настройках безопасности Win7, если не работает - проблема в коде. Если сможете зарегистрировать Ваш эхо-демон в Linux и добиться его работоспособности - Вы просто молодец!